# How can I launch Chrome from Terminal on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I am an aspiring software engineer and in doing some studying and development work I have found that it would be very convenient to have a Terminal command which would launch chrome in a new window with the first argument being passed as the URL to launch (or a local HTML file).  Is there a way to do this on Mac OSX (I'm on Sierra 10.12.4)?  I tried searching but the only guide I found was 5 years old and doesn't seem to work.

Bonus:

It would be even better if we could force the new window to open with the Inspection window already opened showing source code and page structure!

Comment: I found shortly after posting this that we can simply run: 'open index.html' to launch a local HTML file with chrome in a new tab.  This is essentially what I needed.  The next step would be to set up an alias for: 'open -a "Google Chrome" index.html' as a nice shortcut for launching this common filename in our browser.

Comment: Maybe you should put this in an answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered :-).